# Determining parity of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I have this function:

$$f(n) = \frac{(-1)^n + 1}{2}$$

For $n \in Z$ It seems be equal to $1$ if $n$ is an even number and $0$ otherwise:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
f(n) & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
$$

It seems to me that it is the same as:

$$1-(n \mod 2)$$

Is there some other representation of this function which does not use $(-1)^n$? I would like to stay as close as possible to basic algebraic operations like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division or exponentiation and to avoid modulo, floor, ceiling and similar.

Comment: Take the least-significant bit of (n+1). In the C programming language, this would be (n+1) & 1.

Comment: @AxelKemper, I would like to stay as close as possible to basic algebraic operations. Is there a way to express bitwise AND in such a way? I'm not implementing this in a programming language with bitwise operators.

Comment: It's easy to do, if you allow trig functions.

Comment: You could use $(-1)^n$ "hidden" in some other form, like $\cos(n\pi)$, or a similar $\sin$.  This doesn't seem closer to what you want though.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I would ilke to avoid trigonometric functions unless they could be further transformed into some basic algebraic expressions of $n$ (I suspect that sometimes this may be possible).

Comment: But $(-1)^n$ *is* exponentiation, so what is wrong with the given definition of $f$?

Comment: @MeesdeVries, there is nothing "wrong". I just want to find another representation of this function.

Comment: The meaning of " stay as close as possible to basic arithmentic functions and don't use *this list of functions* " makes the problem quite imprecise. For what it's worth, there exists no rational function $$g(x)=\dfrac{a_tx^t+\cdots + a_1x+a_0}{b_s x^s+\cdots+b_0}$$ such that $g(n)=\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, I was imprecise because I suspected that complete avoidance of other functions may not be possible. On the other hand, those "other" functions aren't limited to integer arithmetic ones. In the above comments people recommended trigonometric functions and that's quite interesting. At first I rejected that idea but now I'm reconsidering. Also, in one of the answers below someone proposed an integral. This is also interesting - I need to recall what could be done with definite integrals.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I'm reconsidering usage of trigonormetric functions. Could you propose some formulas with them as answer to my question (not as a comment)?

Comment: @Mark, I'm reconsidering usage of trigonormetric functions. Could you propose some formulas with them as answer to my question (not as a comment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an easier form of your function, its already in simplest terms. What about this function?

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}(\frac{(-n)^n}{n^n}+1)$

It has the exact properties you mention, addition, subtraction, division, multiplication and exponentiation.

There is also an integral,

$\displaystyle\frac{n}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}x^{n-1} dx=\frac{1-(-1)^{n}}{2}.$

How about

$gcd(n,2)-1$

And, although you don't want floor function,

$\displaystyle\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}.$

If none of these work, what's wrong with simply 1 if even and 0 if odd?

As a side note, $(-1)^{n}$ literally means just multiply $-1$ by itself n times.

Comment: Thank you. I need some time to think about it but I find it very interesting. I gave you vote up for now. Some people before you commented on possible use of trigonometric functions. I want to check this out before I formally accept any answer. If you want, you can expand your answer in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

$${1+\cos\pi n\over2}$$ does what you want. Or $\cos^2(\pi n/2)$, which is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages that contain arithmetic also contain integer arithmetic. Sometimes they will do it by having a concept of an integer data type. Sometimes they will do it by having an explicit integer division operator (such as \ in some versions of Basic). Sometimes they will do it by having a "round down to the nearest integer" function called `floor()` or `Int()`.

Let me write this "integer division" operator as `÷`. Then $n\pmod 2$ can be found with `n-(n÷2)*2`, and your function can be found with 1 minus that: `1-(n-(n÷2)*2)`.

There is the prospect of an anomaly depending on whether integer division of negative numbers is mathematically correct. Many languages make $(-1)÷2$ not -1 but 0, so that your function applied to -2 would generate -1 and not 1. If you have `abs()` in your repertoire then you could use it to turn -1 into 1. Alternatively, if you knew that $n$ was never less than (say) 1000, you could just add 1000 to it before applying the function.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to avoid modulo, floor, ceiling and similar integer arithmetic functions unless they can be expressed as basic algebraic operations. Can integer division be expressed as such? Also: my question is not related to implementing that function in any programming language.

Comment: Why would you? Do you like the pain?

Comment: @gnasher729, I'm working with many-hundreds equation systems and using basic algebraic operations inside saves a lot of time of work.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematicians *do* use shortcuts to make their life easier and everyone else's life easier. ⎣floor⎦, ⎡ceil⎤, |absolute value|, modulo operator, $1|_{condition}$ which is 1 when the condition is true and 0 otherwise. There is no reason not to use these.

Comment: I agree with you, but mathematicians also study different representations of some relations to see new ways of using them and to simplify already known related formulas. Now, some shortcuts do make life easier in some situations and harder in other. For example, it may be easier to make some further transformations on $cos(n\pi)$ than $(-1)^n$. There is no reason not to take a look at another representations as it may be beneficial in many ways.